# Implementing key search (by prefix, suffix and regex) in a simple Key-Value datastore

Tags: java, database, datastore

Suppose I am using a simple Key-Value datastore, with String key and value as bytes.

The library for the datastore exposes this method:

```
byte[] get(String key);
void put(String key, byte[] value);
boolean isExists(String key);
void delete(String key);
List<String> listKeys(String key, int maxKeys);
```

This datastore I am referring to is backed by elastic cloud storage and not embedded nor in-memory.

How can I implement a key search for such datastore?

Comment: It's already done. Why not wrap one `Map` implementation?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "key search"? You already have "isExists", and "get", what else you need for "search"? What is "search" for you? What's the signature and behavior that you expect?

Comment: @BrunoReis I mean, like search with Prefix, regex, suffix

Comment: Then you should edit your question to make it explicit that you want to find keys by prefix, suffix, and regex match. Also, what exactly does a "listKeys" function do, when it takes a "key" parameter? Is it starting from that key? Is it starting with that prefix? How do you know it's returned all that was available when you have to pass a maxKeys parameter? If it isn't complete, how do you continue listing? You really need to clarify a lot of stuff here...

Comment: @BrunoReis prefix is actually working since the underlying datastore already implements it, the problem now is search for suffix and regex

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that your goal (quite unclear in the current version of the question) is to support calls to

```
// returns up to maxKeys that would return true to isExists 
//   and match the regex
// for suffix mach, use <prefix>.* as regex
List<String> getKeysByRegex(String regex, int maxKeys);
```

The answer heavily depends on your resources (are you limited in memory? do you have several cores and want to use them to speed up queries or handle more at the same time?), expected use-cases (millions of long keys? of short ones? just a few thousand keys?), and requirements (complex regular expressions? fast response time? low footprint?).

The **quick-and-easy route** is to

- keep an in-memory array of keys, `ArrayList<String> allKeys`, built by intercepting all calls to `put` and `delete`
- use a loop to match up to `maxKeys` keys in `allKeys` when requested to do so by a call to `getKeysByRegex`. You can compile the regex just once, but must match it against all stored keys to see which to retrieve.

That is expensive because it keeps an in-memory copy of all keys at all times, and lookup times are linear.

A **heavier-weight answer** is to

- choose an existing database that can be integrated with Java (which is most of them, using `JDBC`). For example, `Postgres`
- use it to store and look-up keys. You still need to intercept `put` and `delete`, but now your regex lookups can be powered by SQL's `SIMILAR TO` keyword, or even POSIX regular expressions (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html). Depending on regular expression queried for, you should be able to get better-than-linear performance form this.

That is expensive because you need to keep a database server running to handle your regex queries, and even if you do not use such queries, you need to store all keys in it just in case a regex query comes along. It may be worth it because lookup times can be faster-than-linear (depending on query and DB engine handling of regular expressions...), and if you are willing to handle concurrent/distributed queries, ACID-compliant databases make race-conditions easy to avoid.

You can also improve on the simple java version to try to speed it up without including a full DB on the side:

- you can go sub-linear if you build big key-buckets that concatenate keys with newline characters (assuming those cannot occur in normal keys); and tweak incoming regex queries to be multi-line. There is a space-vs-time trade-off here, and `put` and `delete` also become more expensive.
- you can keep caches of recent query results, so that they can be repeated at minimal cost. This is another space-vs-time tradeoff, and also increases the amount of plumbing you will need to implement to avoid caches becoming stale.